# Unable to load web-parts in SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I am trying to add the Modern Script Editor and SPFx web part to my SharePoint online modern page.

it is thrown below error,
[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: not sure if I understand it fully. Are you trying to add the script editor webpart from the spfx samples ? so this one -> https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor
or some other custom one? because the error message is about HelloWorldWebPart

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the  Modern Script Editor and SPFx web part to your SharePoint online modern page?

There is a thread about installing Modern Script Editor Web Part for SharePoint Online Modern Site, for your reference:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing